# Between two dates using loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to be a date wise loop in SQL Server. **Production Date** not part of any Table, It is only virtual Column. Just showing Report.

My query is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductionSummary]
    @FromDate DATE,
    @ToDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE tempProductionSummary

    INSERT INTO tempProductionSummary (OrderID, orderno, StyleID, Stylename, ReceivedQty, CuttingQty, CuttingRejectQty, CuttingTargetQty, CuttingReplaceQty, cuttingtosewingIssueQty, SewingTargetQty, SewingQty, SewingRejectQty, FinishingQty, fromdate, ToDate)
        SELECT
            orderID, 
            (SELECT OrderNo FROM dbo.[Order] 
             WHERE (OrderID = orderDetails.OrderID)) AS OrderNo, 
            StyleID,
            (SELECT StyleName FROM dbo.StyleName 
             WHERE (StyleId = dbo.OrderDetails.StyleId)) AS StylenName,
            --Received Qty
            ISNULL((SELECT SUM(FinishQty) AS Expr1 
                    FROM dbo.CuttingReceivedDetails 
                    WHERE (StyleID = OrderDetails.StyleID)    
                      AND (OrderId = orderDetails.OrderID) 
                      AND EntryDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate), 0) AS ssss,
            --Cutting Production Qty
            ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ISNULL(TodayCuttingQty, 0)) AS abc 
                    FROM dbo.CuttingProductionNew 
                    WHERE (StyleID = OrderDetails.StyleID)  
                      AND (OrderId = orderDetails.OrderID) 
                      AND CuttingDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate), 0) AS ssss,
            --Sewing Line Input
            ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ISNULL(IssueQty, 0)) AS asasa 
                    FROM CuttingToSewing 
                    WHERE (StyleID = OrderDetails.StyleID)
                      AND (OrderId = orderDetails.OrderID) 
                      AND IssueDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate), 0) AS ssss, 
            --Sewing Qty
            ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ISNULL(OutputQty, 0)) AS cvcvv 
                    FROM SewingProduction 
                    WHERE (StyleID = OrderDetails.StyleID)
                      AND (OrderId = orderDetails.OrderID) 
                      AND SewingDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate), 0) AS ssss, 
            --Sewing Reject Qty
            ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ISNULL(CartonQty, 0) * ISNULL(QtyPcsInCarton, 0)) AS Expr2 
                    FROM dbo.FinishingProduction 
                    WHERE (StyleID = OrderDetails.StyleID)
                      AND (OrderId = orderDetails.OrderID) 
                      AND FinishingDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate), 0) AS ssss,
            @FromDate, @ToDate 
        FROM 
            [OrderDetails]
        GROUP BY 
            OrderId, StyleID, DepartmentID 
        HAVING      
            (DepartmentID = 13)
 END
```

Query wise results:

[image]

But I need the output to be like:

[image: 3]

How to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please show your existing query

Comment: dear please see now.

Comment: Where is Production Date in the query, you just need to ORDER BY this on final result.

Comment: Dear @RogerClerkwell, Production Date not part of any Table, It is only virtual Date. Just showing Report.

Comment: I'm totally confused.  You have "expected output" and "But I need the output to be like:" and they look nothing alike.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, Sorry, plz check now, actually both are same, anyway plz see now and plz give me a solution.

Comment: Dear all plz help me, give me a solution.